# Как грамотно организовать хранение данных VUEX

Tags: vue.js, vuex

У меня вопрос теоритический. Есть у меня компонент, который хранил и работал со своим состоянием в store (вынесеном в отдельный модуль). Теперь у меня появилась необходимость иметь несколько таких компонентов с разными состояниями.

Вопрос - как мне грамотно организовать хранилище данных? Я в модуле стора вместо объекта с настройками завожу массив объектов, и каждый экземпляр компонента обращается в стор по своему индексу или ID? Или это можно сделать как-то по другому/грамотнее?

И как мне организовать стор/модули в сторе, если у меня в итоге дерево компонентов (в app несколько компонентов 'А' со своими данными, в каждом несколько компонентов 'В' с разными опциями)? Если делать так-же вложенную структуру в сторе, то каждый компонент 'В' должен знать свой ID/index и ID/index родительского компонента 'А'?

Comment: Не стал писать отдельный ответ. Данный вопрос уже разбирался на оригинальном SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44345704/separating-vuex-stores-for-dynamically-created-components

Там все понятно и без знания языка. У `Vuex` есть такая штука как "Module reuse" (https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html). Которая позволяет сделать состояние модуля локальным для каждого компонента. В посте просто описано, как для каждого компонента с помощью `registerModule` регистрировать свой модуль с локальным состоянием.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы порекомендовал использовать абстракцию где ID - это Индекс массива.
Так вы экономите память. И получаете грамотную логику и архитектуру.

`[ {}, {}, {},]` - база

`[ [[], []], [[], []], [[], []],]` - вложенность

Напрмер:

```js
var A = {
 children: [ B, B, B ],
 // Your properties
}
var c = [ A, A, A ];
console.log(c[0].children[0])
```

Comment: ну хоть кто то думает о памяти в 2017)